# format mysql decimal in a view

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table with a decimal field.

When I create a view and use this field, it comes formatted with thousands separator and appear to be just text where the format function of MySQL is not working.

I'm using MySQL version 5.6.1

my table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE plans_currency (
 plan_id smallint(4) unsigned NOT NULL,
 currency_id smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
 price decimal(14,8) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (plan_id,currency_id),
 KEY plan_id (plan_id),
 KEY currency_id (currency_id),
 KEY price (price),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Any help shall be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Show the view. And btw, this `KEY plan_id (plan_id),` is obsolete, as you have that already in the PK.

Comment: my view is actually extremely simple

CREATE VIEW plans_view AS SELECT price FROM plans

Comment: Can you try to recreate the problem here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/82111/1 and post the new link?

Answer (score 1):

The Mysql FORMAT() function working fine with views

***VIEW***

```
CREATE VIEW myview AS SELECT price FROM plans_currency;
```

Use `FORMAT()` function on View field

```
SELECT FORMAT(price, 2) FROM myview;
```

check out the fiddle demo

**[SQL FIDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ad6a2/1)**

hope this will help you...!